# Backbone.js Model validate method

Tags: validation, backbone.js

How can I validate only certain attributes on a model? Currently I check if the attribute exists in the object passed into validate:

```
validate: function(attrs) {

        // Number
        if (attrs.minimum) {
          if (isNaN(attrs.minimum)) {
            return -1;
          }
        }
        if (attrs.maximum) {
          if (isNaN(attrs.maximum)) {
            return -1;
          }
        }
}
```

but if I want to validate string value then:

```
if (attrs.mystring) {
 // Do validation
}
```

would fail and the validation never takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a little confused by your wording, but I think you want to check if its not an empty string first? and also work out the possibility that it is undefined..if so then this is what you'll want to do..

```
validate: function(attrs) {
    // Number
    if (attrs.minimum) {
      if (isNaN(attrs.minimum)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (attrs.maximum) {
      if (isNaN(attrs.maximum)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (typeof(attrs.mystring) != "undefined"){
      if (!attrs.mystring){
        return -1;
      }
    }
}
```

if you want to only validate one of your attributes, you should write your validate function to accommodate the options accordingly

```
validate: function(attrs, option) {
  if (!option){
    // Number
    if (attrs.minimum) {
      if (isNaN(attrs.minimum)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (attrs.maximum) {
      if (isNaN(attrs.maximum)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (!attrs.mystring){
      return -1;
    }
  }else{
    switch(option){
      case("string"):
        if (!attrs.mystring){
          return -1;
        }
      break;
      case("number"):
        // Number
        if (attrs.minimum) {
          if (isNaN(attrs.minimum)) {
            return -1;
          }
        }
        if (attrs.maximum) {
          if (isNaN(attrs.maximum)) {
            return -1;
          }
        }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

there are many ways to do this, this probably being the least efficient lol but using your example, it will do the job.

also, this isn't really a backbone.js problem per say...but general js

Comment: So there's no way to perform checking of only some attributes? I would have to check for an undefined value for each attribute before performing any real validation?

Comment: sure, if you pass an additional flag into the validate function that specifies which one you want to validate...typically you would want to validate all if nothing is passed,and then only a specified one based on the flag.

Comment: im not sure your question fullfils your request

Comment: but validate() is called automatically when .set is called on a model. How would I pass in additional parameters?

Comment: Thank you for posting an example, but my problem is how to pass the additional parameter into the validate method which is called automatically when set() is used on a model attribute. Will my implementation just override the default validate() implementation?

Comment: well its might not come down to that(additional parameters)...if your validating and your attributes aren't valid, then make them valid before it gets validated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Backbone now supports the has property. So you can do something like that:

```
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            "name": "Kevin",
            "age" : 26,
            "job" : "web"
        },

        validate: function(attrs, options) {
            for(k in attrs) {
                if(!this.has(k)) {
                    return  k + ' attribute is not exist';
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var person = new Person;

    person.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```